# ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info

Tags: sql, oracle, ubuntu

I am newly installing Oracle XE database on Ubuntu by following these steps:

Downloaded latest rpm file for Oracle XE and ran below commands to install the database:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
alien oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
dpkg -i oracle-xe_11.2.0-2_amd64.deb
```

Then I made sure that I have permissions to /u01/ and also it is under dba group.

Now when I am trying to start the database then I am getting issues:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed Aug 13 15:33:51 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> start
SP2-1506: START, @ or @@ command has no arguments

SQL> startup
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/initXE.ora'
```

I see that I don't have the file `initXE.ora` and I have only `init.ora` as show here:

```
$ ls /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/
init.ora
```

#### Update:

I copied `init.ora` file and renamed it to `initXE.ora` file and updated the parameters in it so they point to valid directories, now when I start my database then I am getting error as:

```
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes
Fixed Size          2233344 bytes
Variable Size         616565760 bytes
Database Buffers      444596224 bytes
Redo Buffers            5541888 bytes
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info
```

Comment: If you have reached this question I will tell you that this check the permissions of the .ctl files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are installing on an unsupported operating system and something could go wrong.

The file `initSID.ora`, where `SID` is the instance name (`XE` in your case), is the initialization parameter file (pfile) which Oracle uses when instance starts to load its runtime settings specified by database administrator.

For some reason the installation process was not successful, and you end up with the default pfile named `init.ora`.

On startup Oracle instance reads initialization parameters from the following files in the order of appearance

1. `spfileSID.ora`
2. `spfile.ora`
3. `initSID.ora`

where the first two being binary counterparts of pfiles and are called server parameter files (spfiles), because they should reside on the server side in contrast to pfiles which can be on any side.

You can copy `init.ora` to `initXE.ora` and set appropriate parameters just to check if your instance starts.

However you would better try reinstalling your database checking the messages shown in the output during installation to see if something goes wrong or using supported OS.

Comment: Thanks Yasir, I have created init.ora file and tried to start the database, now I am getting different error, I have updated my post with issue details, please let me know if we can fix this issue?

Comment: Once instance started the next step is mounting the control file to obtain information about physical database structure (datafiles and tablespaces etc.) The [`CONTROL_FILES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams037.htm#REFRN10021) initialization parameter specifies where to find the control file(s). Probably you don't have one(s) in the path specified by this parameter. Usually it has the name like `control01.ctl`.